# n events of one process occuring before m events of another process

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, exponential-function

Assume that you have two independent Poisson processes, N1( t ) with rate λ1 and N2( t ) with rate λ2 . What is the probability that n events occur in the first process before m events occur in the second process?

I know this question has been asked in the forum before. In fact the answer available in text book is

$$
\sum_{k=n}^{n+m-1} \binom{n+m-1}{k} (\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}})(\frac{\lambda _{2}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}})^{n+m-1-k}
$$

Now my doubt is the following:

Suppose I want to find out the probability that 1st event of type 1 occurred before 2nd event of type 2.

There can be two possibilities:

1. One event of type A occurs ------ This means no matter what event occurs next (either of type A or of type B), the condition will still be satisfied.
2. One event of type B occurs, followed by a event of type A. ---- No matter what event occurs next, the condition will still be satisfied.

Now, probability of 1st possibility occurring is $\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}}$ and probability of 2nd possibility occuring is $(\frac{\lambda _{2}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}}) (\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}})$

So, the required probability I get is

$\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}} + (\frac{\lambda _{2}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}}) (\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}})$

Whereas, using the equation given in the book, I get the answer

$(\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}})^{2} + 2(\frac{\lambda _{2}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}}) (\frac{\lambda _{1}}{\lambda _{1}+\lambda _{2}})$

Can anyone please tell me where am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing nothing wrong.

For every $x$, $x+x(1-x)=x^2+2x(1-x)$. For $x=\lambda_1/(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)$, this shows that the formula $x+x(1-x)$ in the book equals your formula $x^2+2x(1-x)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now the question looks very silly.