# Bus stop waiting problem with two events.

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution, poisson-process

I am dealing with a task from the sample set of exam problems in my course of stochastic processes, I just want to understand whether my approach to the task is correct.

**Given**:

We wait at a bus stop, shuttle busses and minibuses arriving at it, according to Poisson processes with respective rates of $2$ and $5$ (That is: $S(t)\sim\text{Poisson}(2),~M(t)\sim\text{Poisson}(5)$). Find the probability of at least two minibuses to arrive before a shuttle bus.

**My attempt**:

Let us denote the time between $m$'s and $(m+1)^\text{st}$ arrival of shuttle busses and minibuses as $\mathbb{S}_{(m,m+1)}$ and $\mathbb{M}_{(m,m+1)}$. We need to find $\mathbb{P}\left(\mathbb{S}_{(0,\geqslant2)} < \mathbb{M}_{(0,1)}\right)$. We can rewrite it as the probability of at most two minibuses to arrive before a shuttle bus: $1-\mathbb{P}\left(\mathbb{S}_{(0,<2)} < \mathbb{M}_{(0,1)}\right)$. Then by formula proposed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/719458/n-events-of-one-process-occuring-before-m-events-of-another-process), the probability has to be: $1 - \frac{2}{2+5}\cdot\frac{5}{2+5} \approx 0.7959$. However, I am not that confident in the results of mine. One of my colleagues has proposed yet another formula for such a probability: $1-\frac{2}{2 + 2\cdot5} = 0.8\bar{3}$. I have no idea, from where does the second formula come, and I am not that confident in the results of mine.

Can you, please, help me to indentify, whether my solution is correct or not?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It seems like I was mistaken in formula interpretation: in my calculations I forgot to subtract the probability for the bus to arrive first. Seems like the correct approach to solution is: $$1 - \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{S}_{(0,<2)} < \mathbb{M}_{(0,1)}) = 1 - \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{S}_{0} < \mathbb{M}_{(0,1)}) - \mathbb{P}(\mathbb{S}_{(0, 1)} < \mathbb{M}_{(0,1)}) = 1 - \underbrace{\frac{2}{2+5}}_{\text{probability that shuttle arrives first}} - \underbrace{\frac{2}{2+5}}_{\text{probability that minibus arrives first}}\cdot\underbrace{\frac{5}{2+5}}_{\text{probability that shuttle arrives afterwards}}$$

Comment: So that the final answer seems to be $\frac{25}{49}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $S(t)$ and $M(t)$ be independent Poisson processes with parameters $\lambda$ and $\mu$. The probability that there are at least $n$ arrivals from $S(t)$ before the first arrival is given by
$$
\left(\frac\lambda{\lambda+\mu}\right)^n.
$$
Here $\lambda=2$, $\mu=5$, and $n=2$, for a result of $\frac4{49}$. Your answer  of $\frac{25}{49}$ is not assuming independence between the arrival processes

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer! You're absolutely right, even visually, since the $\mu$ rate of the second process is 5, then it's quite strange to assume that some process of $\lambda$ rate being less than 5, will have nearly 50% probability of observing 2 instances of the first ptocess before the very first instance of the second process...